# Footer spacing in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I have a huge footer in my LaTeX-document (a table I need on each page), but the table is too high to be in the document even though I use `\addtolength{\footskip}{-30pt}` below that size the footer just seems to grow the wrong way
I am using the package, `fancyhdr`
How can I fix that?

Comment: try our sister site http://tex.stackexchange.com/ for LaTeX questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to accomodate a tall footer you also need to adjust the text height as well.  The easiest way to do this is with the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for sample text
\usepackage[textheight=8in,footskip=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}This is some \\ text in a table \\ this is a big\\ table\\it has many lines\\it's really really tall\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```